# Create Meta-Box on WordPress, add editTable.js and save the field data

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On my eshop (WooCommerce) I want to have size guides. These should be user-filled table rows and columns with sizes about each product.

There is a nice jQuery plugin that you can see here: https://micc83.github.io/editTable/demo/

I used this code that creates a new metabox:

```
// Register meta-box
class WPDocs_Custom_Meta_Box {

  // Constructor
  public function __construct() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
      add_action( 'load-post.php',     array( $this, 'init_metabox' ) );
      add_action( 'load-post-new.php', array( $this, 'init_metabox' ) );
    }
  }

  // Meta box initialization.
  public function init_metabox() {
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_metabox'  )        );
    add_action( 'save_post',      array( $this, 'save_metabox' ), 10, 2 );
  }

  // Add the meta box
  public function add_metabox() {
    add_meta_box( 'size-guide', __( 'Size Guide', 'xlate' ), array( $this, 'render_metabox' ), 'product', 'advanced', 'default' );
  }

  // Render the meta box
  public function render_metabox( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field( 'custom_nonce_action', 'custom_nonce' );
    echo '<div id="edittable"></div>';
  }

  public function save_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {
    $nonce_name   = isset( $_POST['custom_nonce'] ) ? $_POST['custom_nonce'] : '';
    $nonce_action = 'custom_nonce_action';
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce_name, $nonce_action ) ) { return; }
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) { return; }
    if ( wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) { return; }
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) { return; }
  }
}

new WPDocs_Custom_Meta_Box();
```

As you can see in the code above, I wrote `echo '<div id="edittable"></div>';` which afterwards, the editTable.js plugin is converting to the table where the user can dynamically add as many rows/columns they want and then add data in each field.

The thing is, I dont know how to make WordPress save each field so that every product can have their own size-guides.

This is how I initialize the editTable.js

```
// Initialize Size Guide
function print_size_guide_init($hook){
  $screen = get_current_screen();
  if ($screen->post_type == 'product') { ?>
  <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var mytable = jQuery('#edittable').editTable({
    data: [['']],
    tableClass: 'inputtable',
    jsonData: false,
    headerCols: false,
    maxRows: 999,
    first_row: true,
    row_template: false,
    field_templates: false,
    validate_field: function (col_id, value, col_type, $element) { return true; }
    });
  });
  </script>
<?php }}
add_action( "admin_footer", "print_size_guide_init" );
```

And this, so I can load the dependences on admin:

```
// Load Size Guide dependences only on Admin product page
function wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script($hook) {
  if ( 'post.php' != $hook ) { return; }
  wp_enqueue_script( 'edittable-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/editTable/jquery.edittable.min.js', array(), '1.0' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'edittable-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/editTable/jquery.edittable.min.css', array(), '1.0' );
  ?>
<?php }
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script' );
```

Comment: Use acf plugin since its well integrated with wp/woo and can save you all the problems. Since its filled by user i guess its for the order ? So you need to save this size guide values there if i understand you. So use order id and product id as prefix for your meta ?

Comment: No, this is purely informational. No need to set the size-guide values inside the order. I just want the user to create size-guides inside the product page so they can show in front end like this: UK 45cm / USA 40cm / EU 44cm / etc. I wouldn't mind doing it with ACF, i just dont know how to make repeater for columns (now it has only for rows).